# how to delete tiles in the most visited tab

Tags: firefox

I opened Firefox this morning after an update proclaiming more control over content and there are two awful glaring additions to the most visited content (they aren't, Duck Duck go is my browser of choice, for a reason, but Google apparently paid a ton of money for inclusion...Firefox is a fraud. Sigh...). And, I can't delete the additions, so much for content control

Anyway, I don't want to get RID of the tab, I just want control over the tiles. How can I delete the new additions?